# How do I copy the folders inside the nested folders at loadonstartup?

Tags: java, fileutils

I have around 150 folder and inside each folder images are present , I am trying to copy the whole directory inside the other directory . For few directories it is working then after it stops automatically without throwing any error or exception . I am using `FileUtils` method to achieve this .

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectoryToDirectory(originalImageFolder, new File(this.ctx.getRealPath(newFilePath)));
```

Comment: Did you try FileUtils.copyDirectory(File srcDir, File destDir) ?

Comment: are you on Windows or Linux ? I may have an alternate solution for you.

Comment: @VictorS FileUtils.copyDirectory(File srcDir, File destDir) is also not working . I have tried it .
I need the solution for both platforms i.e it should work on both machines.

Answer (score 0):

I provided an alternate solution without the need to use a third party, such as apache FileUtils. This can be done through the command line.

I tested this out on Windows and it works for me. A Linux solution follows.

Here I am utilizing Windows [xcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy) command to copy all files including subdirectories.
The parameters that I pass are defined as per below.

- /e - Copies all subdirectories, even if they are empty.
- /i - If Source is a directory or contains wildcards and Destination
  does not exist, xcopy assumes Destination specifies a directory name
  and creates a new directory. Then, xcopy copies all specified files
  into the new directory.
- /h - Copies files with hidden and system file attributes. By default,
  xcopy does not copy hidden or system files

My example(s) utilizes the [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class to construct a process to execute the copy(xcopy & cp) commands.

Windows:

```
String src = "C:\\srcDir";
String dest = "C:\\destDir";
List<String> cmd = Arrays.asList("xcopy", src, dest, "/e", "/i", "/h");
try {
    Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(cmd).start();
    BufferedReader inp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = inp.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Linux:

```
String src = "srcDir/";
String dest = "~/destDir/";
List<String> cmd = Arrays.asList("/bin/bash", "-c", "cp", "r", src, dest);
try {
    Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(cmd).start();
    BufferedReader inp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = inp.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

*A **combo** that can work on both **Windows** or **Linux** environments.*

```
private static final String OS = System.getProperty("os.name");
private static String src = null;
private static String dest = null;
private static List<String> cmd = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (OS.toLowerCase().contains("windows")) { // setup WINDOWS environment
        src = "C:\\srcDir";
        dest = "C:\\destDir";
        cmd = Arrays.asList("xcopy", src, dest, "/s", "/e", "/i", "/h");

        System.out.println("on: " + OS);
    } else if (OS.toLowerCase().contains("linux")){ // setup LINUX environment
        src = "srcDir/";
        dest = "~/destDir/";
        cmd = Arrays.asList("/bin/bash", "-c", "cp", "r", src, dest);

        System.out.println("on: " + OS);
    }

    try {
        Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(cmd).start();
        BufferedReader inp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = inp.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: ,Thanks for the response but These are the separate pieces code . But I am looking for common code which should work on every platform ( Java is platform independent). Is it possible to have one piece of code for every platform ?

Comment: @NeerajNeeraj As a possible solution, pass in the commands as command-line arguments. When invoking the application specify the command after the name of the class to be run. I suggest this since the only difference between the two files is the command passed to the asList() method. If you want I could provide an example on how to do this.

Comment: @NeerajNeeraj just to add to the above suggestion. You could simplify it even further by only passing a single argument to your application (ex.Linux or Win). In your code you can then control the behavior (assigning the appropriate copy command) using a switch statement or by using a if check condition.

Comment: @NeerajNeeraj My last example is a completely coded solution for both Windows and Linux combined. Did this work for you?

Comment: Hi Victor, this solution is also not copying all folders . I tried this code and it only copied 1/3rd of the total folders present.

Comment: @NeerajNeeraj In your original question you mentioned image files, but are they all image files? Are there any differences in the files that are being copied versus the ones that are not?

Comment: I have the folders and inside the folders I have image files(png,svg,etc) which all can be treated as image files. Among those few folders and their all files are getting copied and rest are not. There is no differences among the files which are copied and which are not.

Comment: @NeerajNeeraj I updated the xcopy command to use the "/s" command for copying directories and subdirectories. If that still does not work you could also add the xcopy "/j" command for copying files without buffering for very large files.

Comment: I did both the ways , but still it is not copying all files.

Comment: @NeerajNeeraj To test this on my end, if I have ~150 folders, how many files would need to be in each folder?

Comment: @NeerajNeeraj change the command to:  robocopy, src, dest, "/E", "/Z",  "/ZB",  "/R:5", "/W:5",  "/TBD",  "/NP",  "/V",  "/MT:32"  You can try this also: robocopy , src, dest, "/MIR",  "/W:5",  "/R:5"